# How to create a div completely inside the borders of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write a code so that whenever I click on a div, another div is created inside it at the mouse coordinates where I clicked. This is what I did:

```
$("#main_div").mouseup(function (e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    $(this).prepend('<div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:80px;background-color:#FFF19A;border:1px solid #eee;padding:5px;left:'+x+'px;top:'+y+'px;padding:5px;"></div>');
});
```

The problem is that once I click near the right border of `main_div`, part of the created div shows up outside the `main_div`. Is there a way to make the created div always show up inside `main_div`?

So that when click near right border of `main_div`, the created div has left position equal to x minus some quantity. I am not sure what this quantity is. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: so it is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ao4eun5a/ ?

Comment: No, because this has the same problem. If you click near the right border part of the created div shows up outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0tyhb7nx/1/

```
$("#main_div").mouseup(function (e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
   var parentWidth = $(this).width();
   var parentHeight = $(this).height();
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    if (x + 162 > parentWidth)
        x = x - 162;
    if (y + 92 > parentHeight)
        y = y - 92;
    $(this).prepend('<div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:80px;background-color:#FFF19A;border:1px solid #eee;padding:5px;left:'+x+'px;top:'+y+'px;padding:5px;"></div>');
});
```

This solution takes into account the position of the container too, so you can move it freely.

You have to remember to set the position of the container to `position: relative;`

Just for clarification: 
162 = 150 (width) + 2 * 5 (padding) + 2 * 1 (border)
92 = 80 (height) + 2 * 5 (padding) + 2 * 1 (border)

You probably better use variables for all these numbers and not hardcode them like this.

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tyhb7nx/2/). using [bumpy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529498/bumpy) solution.
but modified it a bit.

**JS**

```
$("#main_div").mouseup(function (e) {
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
    var parentWidth = $(this).width();
    var parentHeight = $(this).height();
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left + 10;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top + 10;
    if (x + 150 > parentOffset.left + parentWidth) x = x - 170;
    if (y + 80 > parentOffset.top + parentHeight) y = y - 100;
    $(this).prepend('<div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:80px;background-color:#FFF19A;border:1px solid #eee;padding:5px;left:' + x + 'px;top:' + y + 'px;padding:5px;"></div>');
});
```